# Removing page borders when printing

Tags: css, printing, border

My pages have a border, but I don't want that border to be printed.
I've tried everything, but can't figure it out.
code

CSS:

```
#pagy2 {
    background: #f3fff3;
    border:1px solid #c9dbab;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height:100% !important;
}

@media print
{
    .print_special { border: none !important; } 
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="headercontainer" class="noprint"></div>
    <div id="pagy2" class="print_special">
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <table>
          <tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to be overriding the border on the selector you initially set it on, like so:

```
@media print
{
    #pagy2 { border: none !important; } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a print.css with #pagy2{border:0!important;} and calling this in the html?

Answer (score 1):

where did you put this style on the stylesheet?

if you put this on top of the css, it will not work. move it to the bottom of the css page.

Comment: I now moved it all the way to the bottom and it still doesn't work. Drives me nuts.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j83u4Ltr/
Check this, its working
Try to print this page, Border will be removed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you or you have to tell us what "noprint"/"page" css contents inside.

```css
#pagy2 {
    background: #f3fff3;
    border:5px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height:100% !important;
}

@media print
{
    #pagy2 { border: none !important; } 
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="headercontainer" class="noprint"></div>
    <div id="pagy2">
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <table></table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me

```
@media print {

    * {
        color: #000;    
        background-color: #fff;
        @include box-shadow(none);
        @include text-shadow(none);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be solved by using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.print_special').css({ border : 'none'});
});
```

Hope this solves your problem

JSFiddle URL :: http://jsfiddle.net/j83u4Ltr/4/

Comment: No. All these things that should be working aren't. There must be something else going on. I'm going to have someone look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media print {
    html { border: 0 !important; }
}
```